# Iterator and 2d vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator

```
vector< vector<int> >::iterator temp = mincost.end();
vector<int> a = *temp;
if ( *temp != *(temp--) ) 
    return 0;
```

`mincost` is a 2d vector, I want to get the last `vector<int>` of this vector and `last--`.
I don't really understand about iterator :) . Help me !! :D
Thx ^^

Comment: use reverse_iterator to get last cell if it exists; and ++ to get the second last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`minconst.end()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/end/) points to the element [one-past-the-end](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt08ch19s02.html) of the vector `minconst`; it doesn't point to the last element in the vector.

Since you want the last two elements, you should first test to be sure the vector actually *has* two elements in it, otherwise inevitably you'll run into problems.  Then, accessing the last elements in the vector is simply a matter of `*(minconst.end() - 1)` and so forth.

The C++ Reference also has [a description of iterators](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/iterators).

Comment: Your one-past-the-end link is really useful :)

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be helpful to learn about iterators in general.

A quick google search leads to many good references, not the least of which is
http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/iterators

Good luck!

Comment: I've searched but I don't really understand :D .

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to STL containers, think of the end() iterator as something like the '\0' character in C-strings - they define where the end is, but the actual value they carry isn't useful. If you dereference the end iterator, you'll get junk, or most probably an exception.

Try this:

```
       if (!mincost.empty())
       {
             //it contains atleast one 1-d vector and the 'end' iterator.
             iter = mincost.end();
             --iter;
             //dereference iter here.
       }
```

Once you're comfortable with thinking in terms of iterators, look up the reverse_iterator. As Effo mentioned, they are the best solution here.